# TypeScript - Stop Outputting to a file?

Tags: typescript

Is there an easy way to stop `tsc` from outputting to a file? I ask because I currently am trying TypeScript as a static analysis tool for JS files and do not need any compilation really, but I appreciate the hints it gives me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `--noEmit` from the command line or set it to true in the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to configure via `tsconfig.json` file using the `noEmit` option. Example below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true 
  }
}
```